# DuplicateHandle error: error_invalid_handle

Tags: c++, windows, handle

I'm trying to pass a handle from process1 to process2 using the DuplicateHandle function. I obtain the handle using the CreateFile function:

```
HANDLE COMportHandle;
COMportHandle = CreateFile(TEXT("COM5"),
                           GENERIC_ALL | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,
                           0,
                           0,
                           OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                           0);
```

In the second process, I first obtain the process ID from process1 through shared memory, and then try to duplicate the handle:

```
HANDLE pr1handle, CPH, COMportHandle;
pr1handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,FALSE,process_id);
if(!DuplicateHandle(pr1handle,COMportHandle,GetCurrentProcess(),&CPH,PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,FALSE,0))
    printf("Error: %d\n",GetLastError());
```

Then I get the ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.
The processes are not related, I run the first to open the COM port, and then want to be able to read from it with the second process.
Can somebody tell me where the catch is?

Comment: Um, PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE is not a valid access mask for file handles. It is meaningful only for process handles.

Comment: *Never* skip error checking, surely OpenProcess() failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code here:

```
HANDLE pr1handle, CPH, COMportHandle;
pr1handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,FALSE,process_id);
if(!DuplicateHandle(pr1handle,COMportHandle,GetCurrentProcess(),&CPH,PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,FALSE,0))
    printf("Error: %d\n",GetLastError());
```

you introduce a new, uninitialized COMportHandle. So, assuming this is the actual code, I'm not at all surprised COMportHandle is invalid". You will somehow need to get the actual value of COMportHandle from your first process.

Comment: I thought that's what the DuplicateHandle function does. If I could get the actual value from the first process in another way, I wouldn't be using this function at all. Do you maybe have an idea how to do that? I first tried to pass it through shared memory, but I realised that is impossible, since a HANDLE is a void pointer, and such types only have a meaning in the process where they're initialised...

Comment: If you read the comment in the page for DuplicateHandle, it says "The handle to be duplicated. This is an open object handle that is valid in the context of the source process. For a list of objects whose handles can be duplicated, see the following Remarks section." - so you need the original handle from the source-process to be able to duplicate it - how else would DuplicateHandle know WHICH handle you want to duplicate? 

If you are in control of both pieces of code, any particular reason you can't use two threads instead of two processes?

Comment: "DuplicateHandle can be called by either the source process or the target process" Seems like I misunderstood this. I thought the target process (parameter 3) could call DuplicateHandle, and copy a handle(parameter 2) from the source process(parameter 1) and store it to parameter 4. I guess i'll have to find another way to do this.  My first process was supposed to open the port, while the second process is to be a Matlab executable function, which would be called from Matlab itself to perform a read operation. This is why I want 2 separate processes. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Regardless of which process calls DuplicateHandle, you have to pass the integer value of the handle from one process to the other.  In your case, you need to pass the integer value of the original handle from the source process to the target process.  You can do this with shared memory, or by any number of other methods.  The target process can then pass that integer value to DuplicateHandle to create a copy of the handle for itself.

Comment: Thank you Harry, using your advice I was able to successfully duplicate the handle and am also able to use it for the ReadFile function! :)